# Android Retrofit 2 gzip error

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using retrofit2 to develop android app. There is something wrong with gzip and here is the exception stack.
    I don't know where is the exception exactly happens. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

```
Unknown exception
java.io.EOFException
   at okio.RealBufferedSource.require(RealBufferedSource.java:64)
   at okio.GzipSource.consumeHeader(GzipSource.java:114)
   at okio.GzipSource.read(GzipSource.java:73)
   at okio.RealBufferedSource.request(RealBufferedSource.java:71)
   at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:225)
   at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
   at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160)
   at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57)
   at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
   at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
   at com.hello.de.aloha.domain.interactor.RetrofitServerInteraction.callVerifyOauthToken(RetrofitServerInteraction.java:424)
   at com.hello.de.aloha.domain.security.SecurityHandshake.validateOAuthToken(SecurityHandshake.java:178)
   at com.hello.de.aloha.domain.security.SecurityHandshake.requestOAuthToken(SecurityHandshake.java:150)
   at com.hello.de.aloha.domain.security.SecurityHandshake.authenticate(SecurityHandshake.java:122)
   at com.hello.de.aloha.domain.security.SecurityHandshake.challenge(SecurityHandshake.java:70)
   at com.hello.de.aloha.domain.interceptor.SecurityInterceptor.determineNewToken(SecurityInterceptor.java:152)
   at com.hello.de.aloha.domain.interceptor.SecurityInterceptor.intercept(SecurityInterceptor.java:89)
   at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
   at com.hello.de.aloha.domain.interceptor.SendCookieInterceptor.intercept(SendCookieInterceptor.java:46)
   at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
   at com.hello.de.aloha.domain.interceptor.ReceiveCookiesInterceptor.intercept(ReceiveCookiesInterceptor.java:43)
   at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
   at com.hello.de.aloha.domain.interceptor.HttpParamInterceptor.intercept(HttpParamInterceptor.java:75)
   at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
   at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
   at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
   at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160)
   at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30)
   at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127)
   at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Could you post you method you use retrofit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked the code in GzipSource:

```java
    private void consumeHeader() throws IOException {
        // Read the 10-byte header. We peek at the flags byte first so we know if we
        // need to CRC the entire header. Then we read the magic ID1ID2 sequence.
        // We can skip everything else in the first 10 bytes.
        // +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
        // |ID1|ID2|CM |FLG|     MTIME     |XFL|OS | (more-->)
        // +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
        source.require(10);
        ...
    }
```

```
  @Override public void require(long byteCount) throws IOException {
    if (!request(byteCount)) throw new EOFException();
  }

  @Override public boolean request(long byteCount) throws IOException {
    if (byteCount < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("byteCount < 0: " + byteCount);
    if (closed) throw new IllegalStateException("closed");
    while (buffer.size < byteCount) {
      if (source.read(buffer, Segment.SIZE) == -1) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

It seems that your response data violates the format of gzip. So it is advised to check the response data first. You may also need to check the request header you passed in which affect the response data format(ie. accept: gzip).